# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Oracle JDBC

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g

I get a strange Exception in our oracle jdbc driver. How can a native method throw an OutOfBounds Exception? I think it has something to to with the blob in one of the columns.

We use as our server solaris x86, sun java 6, websphere. The databse is a oracle 11 und ojdbc 5.

With my local configuration with windows XP everything works fine.

Any ideas?

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CStatement.t2cDefineFetch(Native Method)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CPreparedStatement.doDefineFetch(T2CPreparedStatement.java:1020)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CPreparedStatement.fetch(T2CPreparedStatement.java:1252)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:373)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:277)
```

In the code I do nothing special. Create a prepared statement, fill in the parameters and execute the query.

```
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryAsString);
                preparedStatement.setObject( [some paramters...] );

                ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                result.setFetchSize(100);
                while (result.next()) {
                    int count = Fields.getFieldsCount();
                    Object[] objects = new Object[count];
                    for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
                        Object object = result.getObject(j + 1);
                        objects[j] = object;
                    }
                    list.add(objects);
                }
                result.close();
```

But I dont think the problem is in the java code because the same code did work on java 5 with ojdbc14 and a sparc solaris. I guess its more a configuration thing.

Comment: Show more code ? What exactly you are trying to do ? It seems like you iterate a result set. Maybe you do not test if it has more results ?